# How to fix callback never being called in Socket.IO swift package

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

When using the [official Socket.IO Swift client package](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift), the callback provided to `socket.emitWithAck("eventName", with: [data]).timingOut(after: 5) { }` never runs i.e. the call never actually times out.

**Is this an issue of the package or am I doing something wrong? And more importantly: is there some way to fix this?**

```swift
// this point is reached i.e. the emit is being called fine
self.socket.emitWithAck("someEvent", with: [["something": "someotherthing"]]).timingOut(after: 0.5) { data in
    // never runs unless server actually gives an ack back
}
```

The socket is initialised as described by them:

```swift
self.socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://[OUR IP]:8999")!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(-1), .reconnectWaitMax(50)])
self.socket = socketManager.defaultSocket
```